# ORA-01780: string literal required using prepared statement

Tags: java, oracle

```
private final static String EXTERNAL_DATA_DIR_PATH = "E:/rptax/input/RPTAX_TAPEDATE_20120406";

PreparedStatement stmt1 = conn.prepareStatement("create or replace EXT_DATA_DIR as ?");
        stmt1.setString(1, EXTERNAL_DATA_DIR_PATH);
        stmt1.execute();
```

this gives me ... java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01780: string literal required ?

Comment: This is DDL, bind variables are for DML

Answer (score 3):

You can't use bind variables in DDL statements such as the `CREATE DIRECTORY` statement.  You'd have to use string concatenation to generate the DDL (note that you're missing the keyword `DIRECTORY` after `REPLACE` as well).

In general, it would be rather unusual that you would want a Java application to be issuing DDL.  Your directory objects ought to be created in the database as part of an installation script at the same time that other database objects like tables and views are created.

As a sanity check, your `EXTERNAL_DATA_DIR_PATH` is a directory on the database server, right?  It's not a path on the application server or on the client machine.

Comment: "EXTERNAL_DATA_DIR_PATH is a directory on the database server, right? " ... yes, I'm working in a sandbox locally b/c of the size of the data set. your answer is helpful thanks.